Text in vscode menus is too big
Lately, in vscode the size of the texts in the menu has changed and is very big :


That becomes an issue when I'm opening a menu with many lines in it because it is too big and we need to scroll inside the menu which is not ergonomic at all:

I looked for a solution, but I did not find any parameter to change the size of these specific menus.
Is there a way to change this ?
